# How to view all colormaps available in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if there is a function call that can give me the name of all colormaps available in matplotlib?

It used to be possible by something along the lines of (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmaps = sorted(m for m in plt.cm.datad if not m.endswith("_r"))
```

But running this in mpl 1.5 does not return the new colormaps, such as `viridis`, `magma` and so on. On the new reference page the code actually hardcodes the names (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)) but I was wondering if a similar query to the above is still possible?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`plt.colormaps()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html?highlight=colormaps#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps) returns a list of all registered colormaps. From the docs:

> `matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps()`
>
> Matplotlib provides a number of colormaps, and others can be added using register_cmap(). This function documents the built-in colormaps, and will also return a list of all registered colormaps if called.

The list this returns includes `viridis`, `magma`, `inferno` and `plasma` for me in `1.5.0`

Answer (score 17):

Here's some code that plots all available colormaps linked to their ID's

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_colorMaps(cmap):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,0.4))
    col_map = plt.get_cmap(cmap)
    mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=col_map, orientation = 'horizontal')

    plt.show()

for cmap_id in plt.colormaps():
    print(cmap_id)
    plot_colorMaps(cmap_id)
```

The output looks like this

Accent

[image]

Accent_r

[image]

Blues

[image]

etc...

Comment: This answer is underrated.  This displays *every* colourmap, especially those not listed on the example colourmaps page on the matplotlib documentation.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

Below is code based on pr94’s approach that plots every colormap with its id in the title but doesn’t open a figure for every single colormap.
I’ve used this to create an overview in one picture of all 166 colormaps (mpl version 3.4.2).
[image: Overview of all colormaps]

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_all_cmaps():
    N_ROWS, N_COLS = 8, 7 # 13, 13 <-- for all in one figure 
    HEIGHT, WIDTH = 7, 14

    cmap_ids = plt.colormaps()
    n_cmaps = len(cmap_ids)
    
    print(f'mpl version: {mpl.__version__},\nnumber of cmaps: {n_cmaps}')
    
    index = 0
    while index < n_cmaps:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(N_ROWS, N_COLS, figsize=(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        for row in range(N_ROWS):
            for col in range(N_COLS):
                ax = axes[row, col]
                cmap_id = cmap_ids[index]
                cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap_id)
                mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                          orientation='horizontal')
                ax.set_title(f"'{cmap_id}', {index}", fontsize=8)
                ax.tick_params(left=False, right=False, labelleft=False,
                               labelbottom=False, bottom=False)
                
                last_iteration = index == n_cmaps-1
                if (row==N_ROWS-1 and col==N_COLS-1) or last_iteration:
                    plt.tight_layout()
                    #plt.savefig('colormaps'+str(index)+'.png')
                    plt.show()
                    if last_iteration: return
                index += 1

plot_all_cmaps()
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can see all available color and their kind in the latest official example in the matplotlib documentation. As of September 2023, the documentation is here:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

---

Here is example usage to display your color in IPython, with bonus from me to use it in cmap.

```py
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib

display(matplotlib.colormaps["cool"])

n_sample = 3
display(matplotlib.colormaps["cool"].resampled(n_sample))

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(
    matplotlib.colormaps["cool"].resampled(n_sample)(range(n_sample))
)
for i, power in enumerate(power_output_result):
    color = cmap.colors[i]
#     plt.plot(..., color=color)
# plt.legend(loc='upper right')
# plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can directly view the colormap instance by just calling its name. For instance, col_map = plt.get_cmap(cmap), and you type col_map in the terminal (e.g. spyder), the colormap will be shown as a plot. However, I am not sure what has triggered this appearance or are there any necessary codes to specify this option?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 (matplotlib 3.4),

#### IPython representations for Colormap objects

> The [`matplotlib.colors.Colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) object now has image representations for IPython / Jupyter backends. Cells returning a colormap on the last line will display an image of the colormap.

So now you can use `cmaps = plt.colormaps()` to get all valid colormap names. The output will be a list of names:

```
['Accent', 'Accent_r', 'Blues', 'Blues_r', 'BrBG', 'BrBG_r', 'BuGn', 'BuGn_r', 'BuPu', 'BuPu_r', 'CMRmap', 'CMRmap_r', 'Dark2', 'Dark2_r', 'GnBu', 'GnBu_r', 'Greens', 'Greens_r', 'Greys', 'Greys_r', 'OrRd', 'OrRd_r', 'Oranges', 'Oranges_r', 'PRGn', 'PRGn_r', 'Paired', 'Paired_r', 'Pastel1', 'Pastel1_r', 'Pastel2', 'Pastel2_r', 'PiYG', 'PiYG_r', 'PuBu', 'PuBuGn', 'PuBuGn_r', 'PuBu_r', 'PuOr', 'PuOr_r', 'PuRd', 'PuRd_r', 'Purples', 'Purples_r', 'RdBu', 'RdBu_r', 'RdGy', 'RdGy_r', 'RdPu', 'RdPu_r', 'RdYlBu', 'RdYlBu_r', 'RdYlGn', 'RdYlGn_r', 'Reds', 'Reds_r', 'Set1', 'Set1_r', 'Set2', 'Set2_r', 'Set3', 'Set3_r', 'Spectral', 'Spectral_r', 'Wistia', 'Wistia_r', 'YlGn', 'YlGnBu', 'YlGnBu_r', 'YlGn_r', 'YlOrBr', 'YlOrBr_r', 'YlOrRd', 'YlOrRd_r', 'afmhot', 'afmhot_r', 'autumn', 'autumn_r', 'binary', 'binary_r', 'bone', 'bone_r', 'brg', 'brg_r', 'bwr', 'bwr_r', 'cividis', 'cividis_r', 'cool', 'cool_r', 'coolwarm', 'coolwarm_r', 'copper', 'copper_r', 'cubehelix', 'cubehelix_r', 'flag', 'flag_r', 'gist_earth', 'gist_earth_r', 'gist_gray', 'gist_gray_r', 'gist_heat', 'gist_heat_r', 'gist_ncar', 'gist_ncar_r', 'gist_rainbow', 'gist_rainbow_r', 'gist_stern', 'gist_stern_r', 'gist_yarg', 'gist_yarg_r', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'gnuplot2_r', 'gnuplot_r', 'gray', 'gray_r', 'hot', 'hot_r', 'hsv', 'hsv_r', 'inferno', 'inferno_r', 'jet', 'jet_r', 'magma', 'magma_r', 'nipy_spectral', 'nipy_spectral_r', 'ocean', 'ocean_r', 'pink', 'pink_r', 'plasma', 'plasma_r', 'prism', 'prism_r', 'rainbow', 'rainbow_r', 'seismic', 'seismic_r', 'spring', 'spring_r', 'summer', 'summer_r', 'tab10', 'tab10_r', 'tab20', 'tab20_r', 'tab20b', 'tab20b_r', 'tab20c', 'tab20c_r', 'terrain', 'terrain_r', 'turbo', 'turbo_r', 'twilight', 'twilight_r', 'twilight_shifted', 'twilight_shifted_r', 'viridis', 'viridis_r', 'winter', 'winter_r']
```

Then `plt.get_cmap(cmaps[0])` will render the colormap in IPython/JupyetrLab.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, `plt.colormaps()` will return a list of all registered colormaps in MPL.
If you are also looking for plotting all of them, such that you can see what they look like, I would suggest taking a look at the `create_cmap_overview()` function (https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/user/usage.html#colormap-overviews) in the CMasher package.
It takes a list of colormaps and creates an overview plot with all colormaps it was provided with.
It also has a bunch of options that you can use if you want to sort the colormaps on specific aspects or group them by type.

An example can be seen here (not showing the image in this post, as it is rather large): https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/user/cmap_overviews/mpl_cmaps.html