# How to get a list of matplotlib colormaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As above. I'm trying this:

`plt.cm.colors.__dict__`

and this:

`plt.cm.__dict__`

But no great success, I get a meshmash of things I'm not interested in. What's the official / neat way of doing this.

Comment: My dumbest way is to pass an incorrect colormap and then it throws an error saying colormap should be one of the following, from their I copy paste those colormaps.

Comment: Do the answers to this question help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34314356/42346

Comment: @mechanical_meat Perfect!