# Matplotlib: How to plot line plots for multiple years with month and day on x axis?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a datarame similar to the following:

[image]

using the following code, I am able to plot a chart:

```
fig , ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,figsize=(15,8))

# colors = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue', 4: 'yellow', 5:'aqua', 6:'salmon', 7:'plum', 8:'khaki', 9:'sienna', 10:'yellowgreen',
#          11:'cyan', 12: 'gold'}
months = euro_to_dollar["month"].unique()

for m in months:
        ax.plot(euro_to_dollar[(euro_to_dollar["Time"].dt.strftime('%Y') == '2020') & (euro_to_dollar["month"]== m)]["dayofmonth"],
                euro_to_dollar[(euro_to_dollar["Time"].dt.strftime('%Y') == '2020') & (euro_to_dollar["month"]== m)]["US_dollar"],
                alpha = 0.5, label = m)
                #color = euro_to_dollar[(euro_to_dollar["Time"].dt.strftime('%Y') == '2020') & (euro_to_dollar["month"]== m)]["month"].map(colors))

ax.grid(b=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(euro_to_dollar["dayofmonth"].unique())))
ax.set_title("Month vs euro_dollar_rate Mean")
ax.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

My questions:

1. I tried to manually type in the colors and try to use map function as below:

```
color = euro_to_dollar[(euro_to_dollar["Time"].dt.strftime('%Y') == '2020') & (euro_to_dollar["month"]== m)]["month"].map(colors)
```

but failed with error: `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 5375    red`. Whats this error and how to handle this?

2. How to I customize the colors for each category dynamically? I don't want to manually type in the colors as below:

```
colors = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue', 4: 'yellow', 5:'aqua', 6:'salmon', 7:'plum', 8:'khaki', 9:'sienna', 10:'yellowgreen',
          11:'cyan', 12: 'gold'}
```

I have seen in some plots where others were using different matplotlib colors by importing cm library from matplotlib. My question is how to assign different colors for N categories dynamically such that each category can be represented by its own color. I have seen others using numpy functions like this:

```
viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 256)
newcolors = viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
pink = np.array([248/256, 24/256, 148/256, 1])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solutions to questions

**1. ValueError**

The error seems to be caused by the fact that `color` is a pandas series object instead of a string or other valid color object. You can solve this by getting the appropriate string directly from the `colors` dictionary like this: `color = colors[m]`.

**2. Extracting colors from a colormap**

The first section of the matplotlib tutorial [Creating Colormaps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-colormaps-in-matplotlib) shows how to extract colors from the colormaps. As it is explained, there are two types of colormap objects in matplotlib (ListedColormap and LinearSegmentedColormap) which have partially different methods to extract the colors. Note that the [documentation page displaying the built-in colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#choosing-colormaps-in-matplotlib) does not show what type of colormap object is used for each colormap. You get that information when calling the colormap:

```py
plt.get_cmap('viridis')
# <matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap at 0x16b5859b790>
```

To get an overview table of all colormaps and their object type, you can run this (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314356/how-to-view-all-colormaps-available-in-matplotlib)):

```py
for cmap in plt.colormaps():
    print(f'{cmap:<20} {str(plt.get_cmap(cmap)).split(".")[-1].split()[0]}')
```

To answer your question, here is a method to extract a list of colors of the number you want from both types of colormaps consistently which you can then access using the month number minus 1 as index:

```py
months = euro_to_dollar['month'].unique()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('any_colormap_name')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(months)))

for m in months:
        ax.plot(...,
                color = colors[m-1])
```

#### Suggestion: use seaborn lineplot function

The code can be simplified by using the [lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn-lineplot) function of the seaborn package. You can choose any matplotlib colormap with `palette` and activate coloring according to the months with `hue='month'`. Here is a complete example.

**Create sample dataset**

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.20.2
import pandas as pd              # v 1.2.5
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.4
import seaborn as sns            # v 0.11.1

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123) # random number generator
bdate = pd.bdate_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2021-07-24')
daily_value_change = rng.normal(loc=0, scale=0.005, size=bdate.size)
value = 1.1 + np.cumsum(daily_value_change)
euro_to_dollar = pd.DataFrame(dict(Time=bdate, US_dollar=value))
euro_to_dollar['year'] = euro_to_dollar['Time'].dt.year
euro_to_dollar['month'] = euro_to_dollar['Time'].dt.month
euro_to_dollar['dayofmonth'] = euro_to_dollar['Time'].dt.day

euro_to_dollar.head()
```

[image: head]

**Select year and plot data with seaborn**

```py
euro_to_dollar_2020 = euro_to_dollar[euro_to_dollar['year'] == 2020]
ax = sns.lineplot(data=euro_to_dollar_2020, x='dayofmonth', y='US_dollar',
                  hue='month', palette='viridis')
ax.figure.set_size_inches(10, 6)
ax.set_xticks(euro_to_dollar['dayofmonth'].unique())
ax.set_title('Month vs euro_dollar_rate Mean')
ax.legend(ax.lines, euro_to_dollar['month'].unique(), title='month')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks so much for a detailed response!! Much appreciated.